# What’s the most efficient way to earn the drone / 107 qualification for a retired ATP Pilot?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

As an ATP-rated retired pilot (30 years experience) and a recreational drone pilot, I'd like to get the type for UAD (drones).
I am not 61.56 current.
What would be the most time- and cost-efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE! Some may be put off by a question asking about "the best way," since opinion-based questions are a no-no here. I think, though, that a word-smith to "time-efficient ways" or "the most cost-efficient way" to do this makes the question sufficiently objective that it should be answerable with facts rather than opinions. And, as a guess, I suspect you aren't ***at all*** the only pilot with this sort of history & experience who'd be interested in getting such a qualification.

Comment: I took a stab at editing the question; if my edits missed the mark, you can roll them back or add further edits as you prefer.

Comment: @joeB, just for clarification, you do not believe that you would be able to complete a flight review and thus qualify as an existing Part 61 certificate holder?

Answer (score 2):

To amplify @KennSebesta’s point, to get your Part 107 Certificate you don’t need to hold a current medical, just a pilot certificate and a current BFR. Then take the online course/test.

The other alternative is to take a written test on basic airspace rules (§107.73   Knowledge and training.) at a test center then take the online course/test. The written tests cost about $140 now and you must sign up for them through the FAA website.

Unless there is some reason you can’t get a BFR, I’d go that route because it’s more fun to talk about airplanes with a CFI than sit in a room and take a test, but it will probably cost more like $300 depending on your access to an airplane.